# Brake sticking on 92 Chevy Sport pickup

Tags: brakes

I have a 92 Chevy sport pick up I have replaced the rotors, brakes, calipers and flex  brake hose on both sides and the driver side is still sticking and the rim gets hot I have checked everything I can think of please help

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something is mis-aligned or bent on the brake assembly. A careful comparison of the mountings of the calipers to the vehicle; loose hub bearing allowing wheel free play; twisted brake hoses; metal brake pipes 'flattened' or bent between hose and master cylinder should all be checked.